# Complementary quadratic knapsack problem

Tags: quadratic-programming, discrete-optimization, combinatorics

The quadratic knapsack problem (QKP)
$$\max_x x^TPx$$
$$\mathrm{s.t.}\;\;w^Tx\leq c,\; x\in\{0,1\}$$
where $P\geq0, w\geq0$ elementwise, is well studied and has existing solvers.

My problem below seems closely related to QKP, but I can't find a way to transform it to a QKP to use existing solvers.
$$\min_x x^TPx$$
$$\mathrm{s.t.}\;\;w^Tx\geq c,\; x\in\{0,1\}$$
where $P\geq0, w\geq0$.

It's easy to translate the constraints by using $y=1-x$, but how can I deal with the objective?

FWIW, in my problem $w=$ all ones vector, and it's exactly the same as in [Knapsack problem with fixed number of elements?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28650/14305) but I would like to have global solution rather than approximate solution.

Answer (score 3):

Applying the transformation you suggested, we get:

$$\min_{y \in\{0,1\}^n} (\mathbf{1}-y)^TP(\mathbf{1}-y)$$
$$\mathrm{s.t.}\;\;w^T(\mathbf{1}-y)\geq c\, ,$$ where $n$ is the dimension where $x$ lives and $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of $n$ ones.

Working with the objective function, $$  \begin{align*} 
(\mathbf{1}-y)^T P(\mathbf{1}-y)  & =  \mathbf{1}^T P\mathbf{1} -  y^T P\mathbf{1} -  \mathbf{1}^T P y +   y^T Py  \\
 & =  \mathbf{1}^T P\mathbf{1} -  (P\mathbf{1})^T y -  \mathbf{1}^T P y +   y^T Py  \\
 & = \mathbf{1}^T P\mathbf{1} - ( \mathbf{1}^T P^T -  \mathbf{1}^T P ) y +  y^T Py  \, ,
\end{align*} $$
while for the linear constraint, $$ w^T \cdot \mathbf{1} - w^T y \geq c 
\Leftrightarrow w^Ty  \leq w^T \cdot \mathbf{1}  - c \,. $$

Therefore, the optimization problem is equivalent to:

$$\max_{y \in\{0,1\}^n} y^T Qy + b^T y  $$
$$\mathrm{s.t.}\;\;w^Ty \leq w^T \cdot \mathbf{1}  - c \, ,$$ where $Q = -P\, $, $b^T = \mathbf{1}^T P^T +  \mathbf{1}^T P $ and we changed sign in the objective function to get a maximization problem. Note the $\mathbf{1}^T P\mathbf{1}$ term can be omitted as it's constant. This is indeed a quadratic knapsack problem. In this case $w = \mathbf{1}$, so the knapsack constraint yields $w^Ty \leq n - c$ thus if $c \leq n$ the problem is feasible.

Some alternatives to get an exact solution (apart from brute force, which could be enough for $n$ not too big and $(n - c)$ relatively small):

- Linearization, i.e. reformulating the model as a mixed linear program. This will result in a mixed integer program (MIP) that can be approached using MIP techniques, e.g. branch-and-bound or branch-and-cut. There are two common approaches here, you can read more about them in the dedicated literature:

  1. **the standard linearization technique**, where a continuous variable $z_{ij}$ is introduced to replace the $y_i y_j$ term. See for example Section 1 of [1].
  2. **Fred Glover's linearization**, which yields a model with significantly less variables and constraints than using standard linearization. cf. section 2.3 of [2].
- If $Q$ is positive semi-definite<sup>1</sup>, then the operator $yQy + b^Ty$ is convex and the problem can be solved using a quadratic integer programming solver (MIQP solver, e.g. CPLEX or Gurobi).
- There's also a custom-made technique using branch-and-bound and Lagrangian relaxation, called Quadknap. It was proposed by Caprara, Pisinger and Toth in [1] and you can read about it [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.2818&rep=rep1&type=pdf). C code is available at [this site](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~pisinger/codes.html).

A couple of benchmarks are available for the different methods, for example [2] which is available [here](http://leeds-faculty.colorado.edu/glover/461%20-%20A%20computational%20study%20on%20%20the%20quadratic%20knapsack%20problem%20with%20multiple%20constraints%20-xQx.pdf).

---

**Remark:** For some of the methods you'll need to have the objective function in the form $x^TQx$, instead of $x^TQx + b^Tx$. As $x$ is binary, $x_i = x_i^2$ and therefore you can bring the linear coefficients to the matrix's diagonal.

[1] Caprara, Alberto, David Pisinger, and Paolo Toth. "Exact solution of the quadratic knapsack problem." *INFORMS Journal on Computing* 11.2 (1999): 125-137.

[2] Wang, Haibo, Gary Kochenberger, and Fred Glover. "A computational study on the quadratic knapsack problem with multiple constraints." *Computers & Operations Research* 39.1 (2012): 3-11.

<sup>1</sup> As $P \geq 0$, it's likely $Q$ won't be semidefinite positive in this case. Nonetheless, I decided to mention this method anyway for a more complete answer.